# Error when importing OOSheet in python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, libreoffice

I am trying to edit Libreoffice-calc sheets through a python script using the library oosheet. I've followed their documentation and it seems to have installed correctly. But when I run "from oosheet import OOSheet as S" in the python shell, I returns this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/herm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oosheet/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
from com.sun.star.awt import WindowDescriptor
ImportError: No module named com.sun.star.awt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Ubuntu system (14.04 Trusty, LO 4.2.8.2), LibreOffice uses python 3.  So this works in a terminal:

```
python3
>>> import uno
>>> from com.sun.star.awt import WindowDescriptor
```

But this fails:

```
python
>>> import uno
ImportError: No module named uno
```

The OOSheet web site does not say that it works on python 3, so you may need to switch to AOO, which still uses python 2.  Or why not just use PyUNO directly instead of OOSheet.

Comment: Ah, i was just running python, not python3. Thank you for pointing that out!